# How to Mail HTML Tag As Plain Text in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

```
I Have One Quiz.aspx(for online test)after Test the generated result should send as mail to Exam conductor,i store Test rresult in session("strResult"),

My Problem is when i am sending "Session("strResult").toString()" in mail,it send HTML Tag Format Like
```

#### Quiz Result

Points: 2 of 2

Your Competency: 100%

Time Spent: 0:0

#### Quiz Breakdown:

**1. Sum of 20 and 30?**

**Correct**

**2. Substraction Of 30 And 20?**

**Correct**

```
How To send this session("strresult"),in plain text like follow

Quiz Result:
Points: 2 of 2
Your Competency: 100%

Quiz Breakdown:
1. Sum of 20 and 30?
Correct
2. Substraction Of 30 And 20?
Correct

How Should i send this in plain text format.
```

Comment: You can not send it as plain text. You need to create HTML for it, But user will see it as plain text.

Comment: @Raghubar sir i send Session("strResult").Tostring() as Message Body,At reciver end Messaage Body Display Like HTML tag Like

Comment: @Raghubar I want To send Session("strResult") as folloeing format Quiz Result:Question Correct Answer

Comment: Ok i will give u example.

Comment: @Raghubar sir Example?

Comment: sorry i was offline...

Answer (score 0):

Example for Create content for mail.

```
 string PointsScored ="2 of 2";
 string Competency = "100%";
 string Msg = "<p>Quiz Result:</p>" +
              "<p>Points:<span style='color:red' >" + PointsScored  + "</span></p>" +
              "<p>Your Competency:<span style='color:red' >" + Competency  + "</span></p>";
```

Now add this to mail body. Like This :-

```
 mMsg.Body = pMsg;
```

It will Display Like this in Receiver Mail.

```
Quiz Result:
Points: 2 of 2
Your Competency: 100%
```